# C# - using different web browser or decoding - IP Camera App

Tags: c#, browser, camera

I'm writing small, C# app for recieving image from my IP camera made with Raspberry Pi and Motion but I can't get any image in window.

WebKit shows raw data, IE (.webBrowser.Navigate()) refuses to load the page (it force me to download video transmission to file).
What can I do ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
    }
 }
}
```

[Webkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgBbb.jpg)

[IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAkog.png)

Comment: You'll need to make sure the page is supplying the video in a format that IE can run natively

Comment: How can I check it ?

Comment: I tried efery format that's available in motion...